# Measurability of Upcrossings

Tags: probability, measure-theory, brownian-motion

Let $a < b$. Let $X_t$ be a right continous stochastic process that is $\mathcal{F_t}$ adapated.

For any finite subset $F$ of interval $I \subseteq [0,\infty)$, define the  $U_{F}(a,b,X)$ to be the number of upcrossings between levels $(a,b)$ in X’s with indices from F. Define

$U_I(a,b,X) =\sup\{U_F(a,b,X): F \text{ is a finite subset of } I\}$.

I want to prove that $U_I$ is a measurable function. I know $U_F(a,b,X)$ is measurable for every finite subset $F$. Any hints on proving measurability of $U_I(a,b,X)$ would be helpful.

Comment: By the very defintion of sup, every supremum (regardless over what set) is *always* the upper limit of a discrete sequence, hence, as measurable as it could possibly be.

Comment: Oh yes. I missed it completely. Doesn't the right continuity of paths is redundant then?

Comment: Another thing is: For each $\omega$, we might get a different sequence of which converges to upper limit. But for measurability, we need one sequence converging to all upper limits. So right continuity has to be used somewhere.

Comment: I think you are totally right. K&S write very tersely "Being the limit of random variables of the form $U_F(\alpha,\beta;X(\omega))$ with finite $F$, $U_{[\sigma,\tau]}(\alpha,\beta;X(\omega))$ is measurable." ($[\sigma,\tau]$ is a usual interval in $[0,\infty)$ not a random interval.)  I am very puzzled. Not even sure if K&S thought that right continuity is needed here. The formulation doesn't give  a hint to that. I think what one can try is to take an increasing sequence of finite sets $F_n\subset [\sigma,\tau]$ whose union is dense.

Comment: Then $U_{F_n}(\alpha,\beta;X)$ ( '@K&S' : please take that $\omega$ out!) should increase to $U_{[\sigma,\tau]}(\alpha,\beta;X)$.